# Why does Java cast the null reference to String "null"?

Tags: java, string

In Java, if I write:
`System.out.println((String) null);`, I get `"null"`.

This seems weird. Does anyone know why the designers chose this approach? It seems to me that this is a case of "creating something out of nothing". I've read the [JLS entry on cast operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16), and it says:

> The type of a cast expression is the result of applying capture conversion (§5.1.10) to the type whose name appears within the parentheses.
>   The result of a cast expression is not a variable, but a value, even if the result of the operand expression is a variable.

Jumping to the [entry on capture conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10), I see capture conversion defined for generic types, but the entry adds:

> Capture conversion on any type other than a parameterized type (§4.5) acts as an identity conversion (§5.1.1).

Okay! On to the [entry on identity conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.1) and there's this:

> A conversion from a type to that same type is permitted for any type.

In this case, the type is `String` but the thing to be converted is `null` and that left me confused. However, it turns out that Java is actually using String conversion for `(String) null`. The JLS [entry on String conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11) says:

> Any type may be converted to type String by string conversion...
>   If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four ASCII characters n, u, l, l).

One problem that this raises is this:

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();
System.out.println((String)map.get("something"));
```

The program prints `"null"`. How do I know whether it was that because entry was `null` versus the String in the HashMap has value "null" (four ASCII characters 'n', 'u', 'l', 'l')? Now I know someone will say that Java discourages the use of [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8), and that the type `HashMap` should be parameterized but is that the solution?

Comment: What do you expect it to do instead?

Comment: Possibly throw a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Everybody ever uses `System.out.println` to try to do debugging; it wouldn't exactly go well if a major tool used for debugging threw exceptions itself.  It's a pragmatic choice to make practical things less surprising, not something that's perfectly logical.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'd even go as far as to say that it doesn't make sense to throw an NPE in general. The intention of calling `.print` is to display something as text (usually in CLI or file). It could be a number, it could be a string, it could be a custom object. The value `null`, is not really different to any of those from a conceptual view - it's just some value. The fact that it represents the absence of value is irrelevant - as far as the printing functionality is concerned that's not an error. It's a symbol that will be put somewhere. Having a symbol raise an error condition is odd.

Comment: I think he is expecting `null` without the `" "`

Answer (score -1):

You are overthinking this. Java is not casting (the value) `null` to (the string) `"null"`. The correct answer is that this is merely an explicit behavior of the [`PrintStream.println(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.String-) method:

> Prints a String and then terminate the line. This method behaves as though it invokes `print(String)` and then `println()`.

Next we consult what [`PrintStream.print(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-java.lang.String-) has to say:

> Prints a string. If the argument is `null` then the string `"null"` is printed. Otherwise, the string's characters are converted into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the `write(int)` method.

(Remember, the type of `System.out` is [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).)

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> HashMap map = new HashMap();
> System.out.println((String)map.get("something"));
> ```
>
> The program prints `"null"`. How do I know whether it was that because
>   entry was `null` versus the String in the HashMap has value "null"
>   (four ASCII characters 'n', 'u', 'l', 'l')?

There's still a difference between `null` and `"null"`, you just can't see that when you print them out with `System.out.println`. They're different values, and they do compare differently:

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();
map.put("foo", "null");
String something = (String) map.get("something");
String foo = (String) map.get("foo");
System.out.println(something == null); // true
System.out.println(foo == null); // false
System.out.println("null".equals(something)); // false
System.out.println("null".equals(foo)); // true
```

Answer (score -1):

It does nothing to do with casting, but with printing: If you cast a `null` to String, it is still a `null`:

```
String s=(String)null;
if (s==null)
{
    System.out.println("It is still a null");
}
else
{
    throw new RuntimeException("This won't happen");
}
```

So you shouldn't have any difficulties to check if a value returned by a Map, Collection, or whatever API is null or not, simply **performing a direct comparation by program**.

In the other hand, never trust the result printed directly to the standard output by a `PrintStream` (as System.out). See the documentation of [PrintStream.print(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.String)).

Moreover: The same ambiguity happens when printing a number or a boolean: If you see on the standard output "123", is it a number value or a string value? I insist: To check values, never trust the appearance of a string printed out to a PrintStream.